# What's the best way to rearrange columns in a tab delimited text file in vim?

Tags: vim

I already know how to do it with

```
:%s/\(\S\+\)^I\(\S\+\)/\2^I\1/
```

but I feel like I'm typing way to much stuff. Is there a cleaner, quicker way to do it?

Comment: Hrm. Wouldn't I have to change it when I had different numbers of columns?

Comment: That's quite easy to do with `\{42}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the columns are lined up, you can use visual block mode by hitting Ctrl+V, then cut and paste.  If the columns are not lined up, increase the tab width first so that it's longer than the content of the columns in question.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I don't think I've fully exploited visual block mode in general.

Comment: Block mode is great. Try selecting a block and using I or A to add the same text before or after each line in the block (like for commenting out code).

Answer (score 4):

Best way to do it in VIM is - not to do it with VIM and (re)use existing tools for the job. *NIX specific solution:

```
:%!awk -F \\t '{print $2 FS $1}'
```

Would pipe the content of the tab-delimited file to `awk` and it will print first two columns swapped, separated by field separator (FS). `awk` can be also found for Windows.

P.S. Initially I wanted to write the same with `cut` but for whatever reason on my system the `cut -f 2,1` (-d is not needed as TAB is the default delimiter) printed the fields in the same order, not swapped :|

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this awk command, but I was actually looking for something more elegant. I also use cut a lot, it doesn't rearrange columns though.